# In a python for loop, how do you handle an iterator that can throw exceptions?

Tags: python, loops, exception, iterator

I am using an iterator, namely the standard library CSV reader, that can throw exceptions. Here's a minimal working code sample:

```
import csv
import sys

csv.field_size_limit(10_000_000)

reader = csv.reader(sys.stdin)
for row in reader:
    pass
```

And here's what happens when I run it:

```
[joel@vm all_recent]$ python dummy_csv.py < mycsv.csv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/dummy_csv.py", line 7, in <module>
    for row in reader:
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 264: invalid start byte
```

What I'd like to be able to do is to log the exception, and continue iterating. What's the pythonic way to do this?

Comment: You could change your loop to *while True* then call *next()* on the reader inside a try/except. However, when this error occurs you may find that the iterator is broken and that any attempt to continue would be pointless. Another option would be to consume stdin to a [temporary] file then open that file with an appropriate encoding

Comment: @AlbertWinestein the encoding is fine, the file is not. So I'm trying to be more robust to a somewhat corrupted file. Maybe there's simply no good way to do that. Thanks for pointing out that the iterator might be invalid after throwing the exception. I didn't realize that. Edit: unfortunately, the python documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) is very light on details as to what happens in that event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract elements from the iterator manually instead of the `for` loop doing it for you.

```
reader = csv.reader(sys.stdin)
it = iter(reader)

while True:
    try:
        next(it)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    except Exception:
        # do something
```

Comment: I was precisely wondering if there's a way to avoid that. I guess not :)

Comment: I just tested your approach, and it works! Thank you.

Comment: You can actually iterate over the reader itself using `next(reader)` so the conversion `it = iter(reader)` is not needed.